How to implement multiple retention policies for the same repo in pgbackrest
We use pgbackrest to backup postgresql data and currently have the following strategy:
Do a full backup every week and incremental every day with a retention policy count of 4.
This is implemented using the following config :
[global]
repo1-retention-full=4

Now in addition to keeping 4 full backups for the current month, we would like to keep at least 1 full backup per month for 3 months which should bring the count to a total of 6.
Basically the 4 last weeks + 1 per month before that
I can't find information on how to implement this without having to build a manual script to do it, any idea?
